# Python Continuous Query Notification listener with Windows service

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, cx-oracle, win32-process

Am building a python script with continuous query notification and trying to build that as a windows service.

Below is my code:

```
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import win32event
import win32service
import win32serviceutil

import cx_Oracle

def notify(message):
    print(message)
    for query in message.queries:
        print(message.queries)
        for tab in query.tables:
            print("Table:", tab.name)
            print("Operation:", tab.operation)
            for row in tab.rows:
                if row.operation & cx_Oracle.OPCODE_INSERT:
                    with open('C:\\Users\\John_\\OneDrive\\Documents\\John Joshua\\UBA\\Work\\NIGERIA\\Banquity\\src\\working_fine\\TestService.log', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(row.rowid)
                if row.operation & cx_Oracle.OPCODE_UPDATE:
                    with open('C:\\Users\\John_\\OneDrive\\Documents\\John Joshua\\UBA\\Work\\NIGERIA\\Banquity\\src\\working_fine\\TestService.log', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(row.rowid)

class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        rc = None
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            with open('C:\\TestService.log', 'a') as f:
                f.write('test service running...\n')
                f.write('write')
                f.write('Calling Queue')
                connection = cx_Oracle.Connection('username/password@hostname:port/ORA_SID', events=True)
                subscribe = connection.subscribe(namespace=cx_Oracle.SUBSCR_NAMESPACE_DBCHANGE, callback=notify, operations=cx_Oracle.OPCODE_UPDATE, qos = cx_Oracle.SUBSCR_QOS_QUERY | cx_Oracle.SUBSCR_QOS_ROWIDS| cx_Oracle.SUBSCR_QOS_BEST_EFFORT)
                subscribe.registerquery('SELECT * FROM CUSTOM.CARD_PRODUCTS')
                input('Wait\n')
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

While starting windows service, it just starts and stops. Any pointers to make this as service would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a definition for your "notify" function -- perhaps the service is stopping with an error? You could add more information to your log file after the call to registerquery() in order to verify that fact.

Comment: It does not exit with error. Can you provide pointers for adding information to registerquery()?

Comment: Well, make sure that registerquery() is actually running by adding a call to f.write() afterwards. You don't want to use input() from within a service!

Comment: Tried all scenarios removing input and adding call to f.write. The bottom line is this, CQN won't work inside windows service. Thanks for your response, Anthony.

Comment: I don't use Windows much myself but if I get a chance, I'll see if I can make this work.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. Really appreciate your responses.